# Custom while loop for hierarchical display of a taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms, hierarchical

I'm trying to build an automated mega menu that loops through all `product-category` terms and displays them in a hierarchical underscored list, as well as including post in each term.

For example, let's say these are my terms:

- Utensils

  - Paints
  - Crayons
  - Markers
- Canvases

  - Cloth

    - Canvas
    - Felt
  - Paper

And any of those terms could have posts associated with them. I need to display the terms in that same order, with their posts listed as children of the relevant term. So, it would end up looking something like this:

- Utensils (product-category)

  - Paints (product-category)

    - Oil Paints (product)
    - Acrylic Paints (product)
  - Crayons (product-category)

    - Crayola (product)
  - Markers (product-category)

    - Crayola (product)
    - Sharpie (product)
- Canvases (product-category)

  - Awesome Canvas™ (product)
  - Cloth (product-category)

    - Canvas (product-category)

      - Flexible (product)
    - Felt (product-category)
  - Paper (product-category)

(I'm bad at making examples)

Now, I can loop through the top level terms, but I'm having a hard time making a while loop that goes all the way down until the next term has no children.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$terms = get_terms("product-category", array(
    "parent" => 0,
));

if ($terms) {
    $output = "<ul class='menu-list sub-menu'>";

    foreach ($terms as $term) {

        $output .= "<li class='menu-item'>";

        $output .= "<a href='#'>\$term = {$term->name}</a>";

        /*
         * Here's where things get weird. I need to figure out a way to
         * loop through all child categories and dislpay them in an
         * unordered list, while also including their own child posts.
         */

        $output .= "</li>";
    }

    $output .= "</ul>";
}
```

I've scrapped it several times and started over. I'll keep updating this as I make progress.

---

Edit 1: The goal is to essentially combine something like `wp_list_categories` with the categories posts.

---

Edit 2: New idea is to abstract the function to get children in to it's own function. Trying this now...